# Внедрение через конструктор

Tags: c#, архитектура

Изучаю внедрение зависимостей, появился вопрос.
Может ли быть такое что два класса зависят друг от друга как в примере ниже. (Внедрение через конструктор)

Можно так делать?

```
public class AService {
  private BService _bService;
  public A(BService bService) {
    _bService = bService;
  }

  public void DoA1() {
    //зависимость не используется
  }

  public void DoA2() {
    //зависимость используется, нужны методы DoB1 b DoB2
    if(condition) _bService.DoB1() else _bService.DoB2();
  }
}

public class BService {
  private AService _aService;
  public BService(AService aService) {
    _aService = aService;
  }

  public void DoB1() {
    //зависимость не используется
  }

  public void DoB2() {
    //для метода B нужен только результат метода DoA1()
    _aService.DoA1();
  }
}
```

Comment: может быть стоит вынести зависимый код в отдельный класс, и *внедрить* его по необходимости?!

Comment: А что насчет бесконечной рекурсии `DoA` <-> `DoB`?

Comment: @Igor изменил код там не должна быть рекурсия. Получается от какого то класса нужно отказаться?

Comment: @Иван Иванов, по моему ничего не поменялось DoA2 <-> DoB2, и вот эта строка странно вообще выглядит if(true) _bService.DoB1() else _bService.DoB2();

Comment: @Иван Иванов, condition что это, откуда пришло? а в общем ничего не поменялось)

Comment: создайте отдельный класс и киньте в него 2 метода доа2, доа1, а вообще сделайте что то типо стратегии и в папаметрах конструктора окажется абстрактный класс или интерфейс (конструктор нового класса)

Answer (score 2):

На яве можно сделать так, на шарпе аналогично, используя функциональные интерфейсы:

```
class AService{

    public AService(){}

    public void DoA1() {
        System.out.println("aserv");
        //зависимость не используется
    }
}

class BService{

    public BService() {

    }

    public void DoB1() {
        System.out.println("bser");
        //зависимость не используется
    }

}

@FunctionalInterface
interface IService {
    void doClass();
}

class ServiceImpl {

    public static void doClass(IService iService) {
        iService.doClass();
    }

}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BService bService = new BService();
        ServiceImpl.doClass(bService::DoB1);//()->{//здесь ваша логика}
    }
}
```

**Если с условиями:**

```
BService bService = new BService();
AService aService = new AService();
ServiceImpl.doClass(()->{
  if(false){
    bService.DoB1();
  }else {
    aService.DoA1();
  }
});
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84678/discussion-between--and-yaroslav).